# entity_create() call to undefined function

Tags: 7, entities

I wrote the following function using [`entity_create`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_create/7), but I am getting an error 'call to undefined function'. Is there anything I need to load so that I can use [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) for my module? I have Entity API already installed but it seems that it is not globally accessible. What I would be missing to have `entity_create` or other Entity API functions available?

```
function customisation_add_newsnap($title, $id, $name, $hash, $datetime, $type) {
  $values = array(
    'type' => 'enews_snapshot',
    'uid' => 6,
    'status' => 1,
    'comment' => 0,
    'promote' => 0
  );
  $entity = entity_create('node', $values);

  $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);

  $ewrapper->title->set(t($title));
  $ewrapper->field_es_id->set($id);
  $ewrapper->field_es_name->set($name);
  $ewrapper->field_es_hash->set($hash);
  $ewrapper->field_es_groupyear->set($year);

  $ewrapper->field_es_type->set($type);

  $my_date = new DateTime('January 1, 2013');

  $entity->field_es_postdate[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
    'value' => date_format($my_date, 'Y-m-d'),
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
  );

  $ewrapper->save(true);

  //entity_save('node', $entity);   
  _x($ewrapper);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Entity API module is enabled?

Comment: how are you calling this function ? `drush php-script your-script.php` ? Is drupal fully `bootstrapped` ?

Comment: Entity API is enabled,and i believe so it is fully bootstrapped.