# Call to undefined function entity_create()

Tags: 7, forms, entities

i try to include a node creation form by a field attach form. So i try to load the entity of a custom content type created by the back-office with is called 'friterie'. But when i call the entity_create function i get this error : Call to undefined function entity_create()

Here is my code :

```
function fritr_register_friterie_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form = array();

    // INCLUDE FRITERIE ADD FORM
    $form['friterie'] = array();
    //module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); this is an old method
    //$form['friterie'] = node_add('friterie');    
    global $language;
    $entity = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'friterie', 'language' => $language->language));
    //$form['friterie'] = field_attach_form('node', $entity, $form['friterie'], $form_state);

    // INCLUDE USER REGISTER FORM
    //$form['user'] = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');


    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Enregistrer la friterie'),
    );        

    dsm($form);
    return $form;
}
```

I don't know why i get this error, i watch on the official documentation and it says i can do it like i did :/

Comment: Can you verify if the `Entity` module is enabled? Do you have it installed?

Comment: Ahm yep i've nit installed entity module... Sorry :s

Answer (score 0):

As Gulok said, check if the module entity is installed and enabled.

Be sure to add entity as a depencencie in your .info file as well.

Answer (score 0):

As tenken said [in related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91398/entity-create-call-to-undefined-function)

```
require_once "./includes/bootstrap.inc";
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```